# split numbers and string to differents columns on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I like to split the column into `str` and numbers.

```
data={"name&numb":["cat 123","34 dog","bird 93","dolphin dof 8 ","lion cat 76","tiger 22 animal "]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I did this so split the numbers

```
df["number"]=df["name&numb"].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Now I like to make one more column so I get only string,
I do not know if it will affect but in the original data, not in the English language

something like:

```
 df["strings"]=df["name&numb"].str.extract('str')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `\D` for non digit data with [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove trailing whitespaces:

```
df["number"]=df["name&numb"].str.extract('(\d+)')

df["strings"] = df["name&numb"].str.extract('(\D+)', expand=False).str.strip()
```

If need all strings one idea is use:

```
f = lambda x: ' '.join(y for y in x.split() if not y.isdigit())
df["strings1"] = df["name&numb"].apply(f)
print (df)
          name&numb number      strings      strings1
0           cat 123    123          cat           cat
1            34 dog     34          dog           dog
2           bird 93     93         bird          bird
3    dolphin dof 8       8  dolphin dof   dolphin dof
4       lion cat 76     76     lion cat      lion cat
5  tiger 22 animal      22        tiger  tiger animal
```